# How can I set the default event to be edited for my custom control in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, events, user-controls

I made a custom button by inheriting the Button class. When I double click the custom button in Designer, it makes the event handling function for MyButton.Click:

```
Private Sub MyButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyButton1.Click

    End Sub
```

How can I make it so that when you double click, it makes the event handling function for another event? For example, MyButton.KeyUp:

```
Private Sub MyButton1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyButton1.KeyUp

    End Sub
```

Hopefully, someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `DefaultEventAttribute`:

```
<DefaultEvent("KeyUp")> Public Class MyButton
```

Comment: @Arjan: Without trying it, I know it works. I know this because I've used it countless times.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the [DefaultEvent attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute.aspx)?

Example from MSDN:

```
<DefaultEvent("CollectionChanged")> _ 
Public Class MyCollection
    Inherits BaseCollection

    Public Event CollectionChanged (ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As CollectionChangeEventArgs)

    ' Insert additional code.
End Class 'MyCollection
```