# How to set the defaul event for a user control?

Tags: c#

I created a user control with an event. I do not want to add the following code every time I add a new instance of the control to a form.

```
Control1.Operate += new MyControl.OperateEventHandler(Control1_Operate)
```

Instead I would like to simply double-click the control and have the above code added by the IDE to the Designer file. By default the Control1_Load event is assigned in the Designer file. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to set a `DefaultEvent` for your control.

Use `DefaultEventAttribute` on your Control class.

A similar question exists:
[How can I set the default event to be edited for my custom control in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548887/how-can-i-set-the-default-event-to-be-edited-for-my-custom-control-in-visual-stu)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

For C# use:

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    //code
}
```

MS Code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are looking for is more like what you have for buttons. You double click on it and you have the event handler method generated for you. But in here, the event handler code is generated on the fly. In your cae, you want to attach, a pre-defined method with the event of the User Control. Try defining some custom properties or event for your usercontrol and then set the default value. For e.g. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx .